# parallelization of a bitmap

Tags: java, android, image-processing, concurrency, parallel-processing

i've an app that loops through a bitmap and places a distortion on it. i've re-written the image-processing part to run in parallel. the distorted bitmap only seems to have the top row of pixels set, the rest of the bitmap is black, indicating that the array from which the new bitmap was made is nearly empty. i think i have a looping problem. i've used executorservice to manage my threads and created 2 threads. thread one should loop from 0 to bitmap.height/2 and thread 2 should loop from bitmap.height/2 to bitmap.height. can anyone help me sort the looping problem. I've not included alot of the code that processes the bitmap but will post it if it helps thanks.

.

```
public class MultiProcessorFilter {



    private static final String TAG = "mpf";





    public Bitmap barrel (Bitmap input, float k){
          if(input!=null){
        Log.e(TAG, "*********** bitmap input = "+input.toString());
          }
          int []arr = new int[input.getWidth()*input.getHeight()];
          // replace the j, i for loops:
          int jMax = input.getHeight();
          int jMid = jMax / 2;
          int iMax = input.getWidth();
          int iMid = iMax / 2;
          int nrOfProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
          Log.e(TAG, "*********** NUM OF PROCESSORS = " + nrOfProcessors);
          ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

          FutureTask<PartialResult> task1 = (FutureTask<PartialResult>) threadPool.submit(new PartialProcessing(0, jMid - 1, input, k)); 
          FutureTask<PartialResult> task2 = (FutureTask<PartialResult>) threadPool.submit(new PartialProcessing(jMid, jMax - 1,input, k)); 
          Log.e(TAG, "*********** about to call task1.get()");
          try{
          PartialResult result1 = task1.get();// blocks until the thread returns the result
          Log.e(TAG, "*********** just called task1.get()");
          result1.fill(arr);
          Log.e(TAG, "*********** result1 arr length = " + arr.length);

          Log.e(TAG, "*********** about to call task2.get()");
          PartialResult result2 = task2.get(); // blocks until the thread returns the result
          Log.e(TAG, "*********** just called task2.get()");
          result2.fill(arr);
          Log.e(TAG, "*********** result2 arr length = " + arr.length);
          }catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          Bitmap dst2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(arr,input.getWidth(),input.getHeight(),input.getConfig());
          if(dst2!=null)
          Log.e(TAG, "*********** dst2 is not null" );
        return dst2;


        }




    public class PartialResult {
           int startP;
           int endP;
           int[] storedValues;

           public PartialResult(int startp, int endp, Bitmap input){

               this.startP = startp;
               this.endP = endp;
               this.storedValues = new int[input.getWidth()*input.getHeight()];
               Log.e(TAG, "*********** input  w = "+input.getWidth());
               Log.e(TAG, "*********** input dim  h = "+input.getHeight());
           }

           public void addValue(int p, int result) {
                 storedValues[p] = result;
                // Log.e(TAG, "*********** p = " + p + "result = " + result);
           }

           public void fill(int[] arr) {
               int x = 0;
              // Log.e(TAG, "*********** startP = "+startP + "  endP = " + endP);
              for (int p = startP; p < endP; p++, x++)
                 arr[p] = storedValues[p];

              Log.e(TAG, "*********** arr = " + arr[x]);
              }
           }




    public class PartialProcessing implements Callable<PartialResult> {
        int startJ;
        int endJ;

       // ... other members needed for the computation 

        public PartialProcessing(int startj, int endj, Bitmap input, float k) {

            this.startJ = startj;
            this.endJ = endj;
            this.input = input;
            this.k = k;


        }

        int [] getARGB(Bitmap buf,int x, int y){

            method for processing

        }

        //... add other methods needed for the computation that where in class Filters

        float getRadialX(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){

            method for processing
          }

          float getRadialY(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){

           method for processing
          }



          float calc_shift(float x1,float x2,float cx,float k){

           method for processing
          }


          void sampleImage(Bitmap arr, float idx0, float idx1)
          {

           method for processing
          }


        // this will be called on some new thread
        @Override public PartialResult call() { 

             PartialResult partialResult = new PartialResult(startJ, endJ,input);



            int p = startJ; // not 0! at the start since we don't start at j = 0
            int origPixel = 0;
            int color = 0;
            int i;
            for (int j = startJ; j <  endJ; j++){
                // Log.e(TAG, "*********** j = "+j );

                for ( i = 0; i < width; i++, p++){
                    //... copy the rest of the code
                    // Log.e(TAG, "*********** i = " + i);


             origPixel = input.getPixel(i,j);

             float x = getRadialX((float)j,(float)i,centerX,centerY,k);


             float y = getRadialY((float)j,(float)i,centerX,centerY,k);

             sampleImage(input,x,y);

             color = ((s[1]&0x0ff)<<16)|((s[2]&0x0ff)<<8)|(s[3]&0x0ff);

             if(((i-centerX)*(i-centerX) + (j-centerY)*(j-centerY)) <= 5500){

                //arr[p]=color;
                 partialResult.addValue(p, color);
                // Log.e(TAG, "*********** color = " + color);

            }else{

                //arr[p]=origPixel;
                partialResult.addValue(p, origPixel);



            }

                }
                     // partialResult.addValue(p, color);
        }
            return partialResult;
    }


}

}//end of MultiProcesorFilter
```

.

**[update 1]**

.

```
07-31 13:50:29.548: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** bitmap input = android.graphics.Bitmap@43cd2780
07-31 13:50:29.553: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** NUM OF PROCESSORS = 1
07-31 13:50:29.553: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** about to call task1.call()
07-31 13:50:29.558: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** input  w = 150
07-31 13:50:29.563: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** input  h = 150
07-31 13:50:30.348: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** just called part1.call()
07-31 13:50:30.348: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** result1 arr length = 22500
07-31 13:50:30.348: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** about to call part2.()
07-31 13:50:30.353: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** input  w = 150
07-31 13:50:30.353: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** input  h = 150
07-31 13:50:31.143: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** just called part2.call()
07-31 13:50:31.143: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** result2 arr length = 22500
07-31 13:50:31.173: DEBUG/WifiService(1911): ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED pluggedType: 2
07-31 13:50:31.183: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** dst2 is not null
07-31 13:50:31.188: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** bitmap input = android.graphics.Bitmap@43ccb060
07-31 13:50:31.253: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3354): GC freed 652 objects / 124416 bytes in 65ms
07-31 13:50:31.258: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** NUM OF PROCESSORS = 1
07-31 13:50:31.258: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** about to call task1.call()
07-31 13:50:31.258: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** input  w = 150
07-31 13:50:31.258: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** input  h = 150
07-31 13:50:32.093: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** just called part1.call()
07-31 13:50:32.093: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** result1 arr length = 22500
07-31 13:50:32.093: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** about to call part2.()
07-31 13:50:32.098: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** input  w = 150
07-31 13:50:32.098: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** input  h = 150
07-31 13:50:33.078: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** just called part2.call()
07-31 13:50:33.078: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** result2 arr length = 22500
07-31 13:50:33.083: ERROR/mpf(3354): *********** dst2 is not null
```

.

**[update2]**

```
 public void fill(int[] arr) {
               int x = 0;
               Log.e(TAG, "*********** startP = "+startP + "  endP = " + endP);

              for (int p = startP; p < endP; p++, x++){
                 arr[p] = storedValues[p];
              }

              Log.e(TAG, "*********** arr size = "+arr.length);
              Log.e(TAG, "*********** storedValues size = "+storedValues.length);
              }

           }
```

.

```
07-31 14:26:18.788: ERROR/mpf(6380): *********** just called task1.get()
07-31 14:26:18.788: ERROR/mpf(6380): *********** startP = 0  endP = 74
07-31 14:26:18.788: ERROR/mpf(6380): *********** arr size = 22500
07-31 14:26:18.788: ERROR/mpf(6380): *********** storedValues size = 22500
07-31 14:26:18.788: ERROR/mpf(6380): *********** result1 arr length = 22500
07-31 14:26:18.788: ERROR/mpf(6380): *********** about to call task2.get()
07-31 14:26:18.818: ERROR/mpf(6380): *********** just called task2.get()
07-31 14:26:18.818: ERROR/mpf(6380): *********** startP = 75  endP = 149
07-31 14:26:18.818: ERROR/mpf(6380): *********** arr size = 22500
07-31 14:26:18.818: ERROR/mpf(6380): *********** storedValues size = 22500
07-31 14:26:18.818: ERROR/mpf(6380): *********** result2 arr length = 22500
07-31 14:26:18.823: ERROR/mpf(6380): *********** dst2 is not null
07-31 14:26:18.823: ERROR/mpf(6380): *********** bitmap input = android.graphics.Bitmap@43ce62c0
```

.

**[update3]**

```
public void fill(int[] arr) {

               Log.e(TAG, "*********** startP = "+startP + "  endP = " + endP);

              for (int p = startP; p < endP; p++){
                  for(int b=0;b<150;b++,x++)
                 arr[x] = storedValues[x];
              }

              Log.e(TAG, "*********** arr size = "+arr.length);
              Log.e(TAG, "*********** storedValues size = "+storedValues.length);
              Log.e(TAG, "*********** x = "+x);
              }

           }
```

Comment: Does this work if you use the two `PartialProcessing` calls one after the other?

Comment: @paulo ebermann hi, not sure what you mean. i have 2 partialprocessing calls one after the other and only the first row of the bitmap is written to the array in storedValues. storedValues is used in PartialResult.fill() to populate an array from which the ultimate bitmap is derived

Comment: The question is, is your problem dependent on doing this concurrently, or does it occur for sequential processing, too? Knowing this, you can find the problem easier by reducing your program.

Comment: @paulo ebermann erm you'll have to bear with me on this as i'm new to concurrency etc. the code that i've posted is part of my old app that i've re-written in parallel. the old code works fine and processes the image correctly. it does have steps that process the image sequentially ie one method needs to execute before another, but what i'm trying to do here(above) is use the old processing code that works but split it over multiple processors that give a partial result. all the partial results will be put back together to form the end result, which i believe is parallel programing.

Comment: so i think there is a problem in how the above code iterates through the bitmap as not all the pixels are getting processed. hope that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet a full answer, but too large for a comment.

I can't really test your program, but for debugging purposes please change this method:

```
public Bitmap barrel (Bitmap input, float k){
    if(input!=null){
       Log.e(TAG, "*********** bitmap input = "+input.toString());
    }
    int []arr = new int[input.getWidth()*input.getHeight()];
      // replace the j, i for loops:
    int jMax = input.getHeight();
    int jMid = jMax / 2;
    int iMax = input.getWidth();
    int iMid = iMax / 2;
    int nrOfProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    Log.e(TAG, "*********** NUM OF PROCESSORS = " + nrOfProcessors);

    PartialProcessing part1 = new PartialProcessing(0, jMid - 1, input, k); 
    PartialProcessing part2 = new PartialProcessing(jMid, jMax - 1,input, k); 
    Log.e(TAG, "*********** about to call task1.call()");
    try{
       PartialResult result1 = part1.call();// blocks until the thread returns the result
       Log.e(TAG, "*********** just called part1.call()");
       result1.fill(arr);
       Log.e(TAG, "*********** result1 arr length = " + arr.length);

       Log.e(TAG, "*********** about to call part2.()");
       PartialResult result2 = part2.call(); // blocks until the thread returns the result
       Log.e(TAG, "*********** just called part2.call()");
       result2.fill(arr);
       Log.e(TAG, "*********** result2 arr length = " + arr.length);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap dst2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(arr,input.getWidth(),input.getHeight(),input.getConfig());
    if(dst2!=null)
        Log.e(TAG, "*********** dst2 is not null" );
    return dst2;
}
```

This would be a serial variant of your program. Run this, and check if it works.

- If it does, we have a problem with the concurrency.
- If it does not work, the problem is in your actual implementation, independent of the concurrency.

---

> the nearly empty bitmap is still the result of the processing

Okay, so we know this is not concurrency-related. Let's look at the points where the pixels are set.
One is here, in PartialResult:

```
  public void fill(int[] arr) {
       int x = 0;
      // Log.e(TAG, "*********** startP = "+startP + "  endP = " + endP);
      for (int p = startP; p < endP; p++, x++)
         arr[p] = storedValues[p];

      Log.e(TAG, "*********** arr = " + arr[x]);
      }
  }
```

This sets the elements of `arr` from `startP` to `endP` to some stored values. Now please have a look at the actual values of `startP` and `endP` in comparison to the sizes of `storedValues` and `arr`, and I suppose you'll get why there is only a first line of pixels.

---

After update 3:

It gets better. Now have a look where your `x` starts in the `fill` method (in the old one it was `0`, I'm not sure about the new one - it should be `startP*150`), and where your `p` starts in the `call` method (it starts at `startJ` - I think it should start at `startJ * 150`, too).

Comment: ebermann thanks for getting back. i've updated my post to include the logging from running your code

Comment: the nearly empty bitmap is still the result of the processing.

Comment: ebermann the bitmap 150X150, which equals 22500. the arr and storedValues arrays are set to this length so they can be populated with all the pixel data. startP and endP have values 0,74 on the first call and 75,149 on the 2nd call. so in effect the bitmap is being split in 2 height-wise over the 2 calls. in the fill() loop i is set to bitmap.width. so in my thinking every pixel ought to be checked. it must be that the same line is over-written with the pixel data?

Comment: Your `fill` method copies only data from the first line (and only half of a line in each case - 75 pixels), instead of copying the whole half of the array (75*150 pixels).

Comment: ebermann ok i've got a liitle closer[update3]. i've made x a class variable and created an inner loop for the width. the bitmap is now half full. the top half is ok whilst the bottom half still remains black/empty. i can't think why i'm not looping the entire bitmap. there are 2 tasks 0-74 75-149, thats the height taken care of. the inner loop runs to 150, which is the width. in my eyes the whole bitmap should be populated

Comment: ebermann SOLVED:) hey thanks for being patient! parallelizing for loops makes it more difficult to track what's going on, plus i'm new to this. there are black lines through the bitmap but it's all there now. i'll look into why. thanks again